# Can a vSphere/ESXi host be used for automatic provisioning of instances?

Tags: esxi

VMWare's products and service offerings are absolutely indecipherable to me. I know I have a single ESXi (vSphere?) host using the free license.

I know that there a number of tools can be used to bring up VEs using API calls. But trying to get vagrant-vsphere to run, it wants me to provide a "template" to clone from, and as far as I can figure out templates are only supported when using "vCenter".

Are people doing automatic provisioning using a simple, single ESXi instance, and what tools are they using?

Answer (score 0):

First, here is a guide that attempts to outline many of the VMware products: 
http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/vmware-product-guide.pdf

I agree that there are so many of them, with many overlapping, that it makes the tough to distinguish without using them frequently.

I'd say there are a few main ways to do automatic provisioning in general:

1. [VMware vSphere Auto-Deploy](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features/auto-deploy.html) can be used to automatically deploy the ESX(i) hosts themselves.
2. [VMware vCenter Orchestrator](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-orchestrator/) can be used to automatically deploy virtual machines:
3. VMware vSphere PowerCLI (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/‎) is a Powershell-based command-line scripting tool for writing your own scripts to deploy and manage virtual machines, ESX(i) hosts, etc.

I doubt, though, that too many people are doing too much automation on a "simple, single ESXi instance" since that's reasonably straightforward to manage.  However, there is certainly nothing stopping you, so feel free to try it out!